# Php/Javascript to make a browser game?

Tags: php, javascript

I've been on and off intrested in making a text based browser game. 
I have been turned off by the idea because of the daunting amount of things to learn.

PHP (or another sever side scripting language)
Javascript
HTML
MySql

And the fact of severs and apache..

Can I just pay for web hosting and by-pass having to set-up apache?

Also how long will it take me to learn all thoose things well enough to start work on my game?

Should I just stick with Flash and then C# for XNA?

Comment: What technologies are you familiar with ? Learning a whole new set of skills has merit, but not if you want to be productive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Do you have a specific game in mind?
- Does it need to be multiplayer?
- In the initial stages, does it require server interaction at all?

Conversely,

- Are you interested in the possibility of building a working game first, and adding in features like saving high scores, multiplayer, or other server-interactions later?
- Is a self-contained game like [nethack](http://www.nethack.org/) or [Hitchhikers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Hitchhiker%27s_Guide_to_the_Galaxy_%28computer_game%29) a good starting place for you?

If your initial game does not require server interaction, you can build quite complex games using only [HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html?sort=active) and [JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript?sort=active). This will reduce the number of concepts and languages you need to learn up front.

Once you have had some practice building non-trivial games in HTML and JavaScript, you can then add in features like server-integration, and learn a server-side language like PHP, Python, Perl, ASP.NET, or Ruby...

You can definitely pay for hosting, and eliminate the effort of setting up and maintaining a server yourself. A quick search will find you a number of web hosting sites to choose from.

Comment: Alternately, if you definitely want server-interaction, but can sacrifice some front-end functionality in the beginning, you could start with PHP+HTML, and leave the javascript until later...

Comment: Example browser game, with no server interactions: http://www.dhtmlgoodies.com/scripts/game_solitaire/game_solitaire.html

Comment: Example browser text-adventure games with server interaction, but no javascript: http://rinkworks.com/adventure/

Comment: Agree, eliminating the server side part is good idea. If that just doesn't work for the game, find a different project for learning JavaScript. One, by the way, does not actually have to pay for web hosting, many free web hosting providers will do fine as a PHP playground. Awardspace is one of them.

Answer (score 2):

Just install [XAMPP](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-windows.html), which is basically the lazy man's Apache/PHP/MySQL setup in 1 click.  You just install it and it does all the work, nothing for you to setup nor config.

Don't let the complexity of PHP/HTML/Javascript set you off, we all hard to start somewhere.  Just start with the parts you know how to make, then look around for each individual problem.  Being motivated is key to learning anything, and if you have something you enjoy working on, you won't have a problem learning what you need to pull this off.

Answer (score 0):

I believe sticking with flash would make things easier, as syncing multiplayer with javascript and PHP isnt going to be easy.

Comment: It's not easier in Flash. Things like synchring have to happen on the server anyway. Flash is only for the client layer where you can also use JavaScript.

Comment: As far as I know flash can create lasting connections, unlike javascript, which can only make HTTP requests.

But then again, writing a seperate server might be even harder. *shrug*

Comment: It would be text based so stats would get saved to a database and player profiles can be viewed by other players..like Urban Dead.

Comment: You should indeed stick with php and JS then.

Answer (score 0):

It depends how complex the game you want to make is. You can easily learn some basic PHP and javascript inside of a month (like pretty much any other language), but it'll take a lifetime to master (like any other language).

I would recommend you start out small - plan to implement just a subset of your features, and take them on one at a time.

I would plan to use libraries / frameworks. For Javascript I would currently recommend JQuery because I find it easy to use, it has a large community and it's well documented. Using a library like JQuery allows you to easily ignore a lot of the browser specific details, since they deal with all that nonsense for you.

For PHP I personally use Zend Framework - this is a massive beast that isn't always the best documented, but if you start with the "Quick Start" tutorial and then only look at features as you need them, you shouldn't get overwhelmed too easily. One of the great things about Zend is that you can pick and choose what features you want to use without hassle.

With regards to servers, yes you can use a web host and bypass setting up a full server yourself very easily and cheaply. You can find local installations (eg. XAMPP) that will allow you to quickly set up a local install of Apache, PHP and MySQL to get started with.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if you're developing an MMO or want to offer multiplayer support, you're going to need to learn PHP and mySQL. In theory, you could go ASP.NET instead, but I would strongly advise against it, since Microsoft servers cost more to rent, and since PHP/mySQL is much better documented and easier for beginners to learn. If you're building a single-player game, Javascript and HTML could technically be adequate, but knowing PHP will still make your life easier, in the long run.

Although you should probably set up a LAMP stack (Linux Apache mySQL PHP) on a local network so you understand how it works, hosting your own server almost never makes sense for a production environment. You could, however, save yourself some money by developing the game on your own LAMP stack. Alternately, most shared hosts (around $80 / year) provide support for PHP and mySQL, and this would be perfectly adequate for building your game. Eventually, once you're ready to launch -- and assuming it becomes even marginally popular -- you're going to need at least a VPS, and possibly a dedicated server.

Finally, a note on Flash:
In the last few years, the popularity of mobile devices has skyrocketed, and this presents a risk for Flash games, since Apple refuses to support the plugin. If you need advanced graphics support, a more timely alternative would be HTML5. Unfortunately, this carries its own set of drawbacks: namely, since it's a long way off from official release, it's not yet universally supported, and features that are supported will vary from one browser to another. So basically, HTML5 is the future, and Flash is the past. The best option for right now? Probably Javascript; you might be surprised what JS can achieve, when properly combined with CSS, and you'll need it for AJAX functions anyway. Best of all, it's supported by virtually every device and browser.

So, in conclusion, I'm recommending that you learn HTML, CSS, PHP, mySQL and Javascript, and don't be intimidated by that variety of languages; the more you learn, the more easily you learn the rest.